# Anonymous classes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, eigenclass

I have two questions:

1. Does method `f_1` belong to the metaclass anonymous class?
2. Does method `f_2` belong to the anonymous class?

related to the following code:

```
car = "car"

class << car
  def self.f_1
    puts "f_1"
  end
  def f_2
    puts "f_2"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, terminology is frangible, but FWIW I would say your class wasn't really an anonymous class.  As for belonging, both of these methods only exist in the car object.

I'll be honest and admit that I'm a little vague about the difference between a class method and an instance method when the class is defined against an individual object like this -- I would guess that if there is any difference, it will be an obscure one that will make your code much harder to read ;)

Update: You might find [this](http://viewsourcecode.org/why/hacking/seeingMetaclassesClearly.html) helpful, if you've not seen it before.   (Personally, it makes my head hurt, but everyone's different...)

Answer (score 4):

Since ruby's own API uses the term "[singleton class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001013)," I'd say the following are true:

1. `f_1` is a class method on car's singleton class and can be called like this:

   ```
   car.singleton_class.f_1
   ```
2. `f_2` is an instance method on car's singleton class and can be called like this:

   ```
   car.f_2
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression that an anonymous class is a class that has no name:

```
my_class = Class.new
my_class.name # => nil
```

However, the Pickaxe refers to it as a unnamed class rather than as an anonymous class.

Comment: If you create a class and assign it a constant My_slass it will have a name.

Answer (score 0):

A reformulation of Rob Davis' answer:

1. The method-owner of `:f_1` is `car.singleton_class.singleton_class`.
2. The method-owner of `:f_2` is `car.singleton_class`.

The chain `car` → `car.singleton_class` → `car.singleton_class.singleton_class` corresponds to the bottom row in the diagram at http://www.atalon.cz/rb-om/ruby-object-model/#sc-inheritance-sample.

Notes:

- The code does NOT create any new class (in particular, no anonymous class is created).
- In most Ruby programs, eigenclasses of eigenclasses are NOT made "actual" (see http://www.atalon.cz/rb-om/ruby-object-model/#actual-lists).